# How do you autoplay a video on a specific slide within owl carousel, stop and then go to next slide?

Tags: jquery, html, owl-carousel

I am using owl carousel within a number of html pages to run a non-paginated slider/carousel of images that will be played on an LCD TV screen for display purposes only (but through a web browser) - the issue of it being bad practice is negated because it's not being used online.

One of the slides within the page is to contain an mp4 video locally hosted on the same box as the html pages.

My markup looks like:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
            pagination : false,
            autoPlay : true,
            items:1,
            merge:true,
            loop:true,
            margin:10,
            video:true,
            lazyLoad:true,
            center:true,

        })

    })
    </script>

    <style>

        #owl-demo .item-video img{
            display: block;
            width: 768px;
            width:   1280px;
            padding: 0;
            margin:  0;
            overflow: hidden;
            top:  0;
            left: 0;
        } 

    </style>

    </head>
        <body>
                  <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">

                        <div class="item-video"><img src="images/1.jpg" /></div>
                        <div class="item-video"><img src="images/2.jpg" /></div>
                        <div class="item-video"><img src="images/3.jpg" /></div>
                        <div class="item-video">
                          <video width="1280" height="768" controls>
                            <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item-video"><img src="images/4.jpg" /></div>
                        <div class="item-video"><img src="images/5.jpg" /></div>
                        <div class="item-video"><img src="images/6.jpg" /></div>
                        <div class="item-video"><img src="images/7.jpg" /></div>
                        <div class="item-video"><img src="images/8.jpg" /></div>
                        <div class="item-video"><img src="images/9.jpg" /></div>
                        <div class="item-video"><img src="images/10.jpg" /></div>

                  </div>
        </body>


    </html>
```

The video runs for about 2 and a half minutes.

I am wondering how I could make the slide  containing the video stop and play the video for the full length, then go to the next slide and loop through them normally, before starting again and doing the same again.

I tried using:

```
    <video width="1280" height="768" controls autoplay>
```

On the video object itself but this only runs the video once when the page loads up and the sound can be heard as the other slides loop.

I am a bit clueless when it comes to jquery, so any help greatly appreciated.